# The rate doesn't work, it always output 0.000

Tags: c, floating-point

Here is my code.

```
 float total,rate;        
 rate = score / 25;       
 printf("Total: %f", rate);
```

But this doesn't work; it always outputs 0.000. Can you help?

Comment: try `/ 25` change to `/ 25.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here and say that you have score declared as an int. int divided by int will always result in an int. You can fix this by either:

1. declare `score` as float
2. cast it as `(float)score`
3. multiply it with a float `rate = score * 1.0f / 25`
4. change 25 to `25.0f`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
rate = score / 25.0;       
printf("Total: %f", rate);
```

Or:

```
rate = (float) score / 25;       
printf("Total: %f", rate);
```

An `int` divided by an `int` will always be an `int`, with everything "after the decimal" truncated.